# Springboot JPA @Query Rest Giving PersistentEntity must not be null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to put together a simple rest service with `springboot 1.4.3`. I have it up and running with simple queries like `findByRecid`, however when I try to do a `@Query` statement on that same entity, I get the below error message

> {"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}

Further, if I use a fully qualified name for the entity in the query, Intellij tells me that the class isn't an entity, even though it's marked with @Entity and works with the standard springboot queries. Please assist if possible - I've been trying to figure this one out for days. Below is the query for your reference

```
@Query("SELECT new com.test.domain.ReceivableBeans.RecAgeBucketGroupAmountSum(r.agebucket, sum(r.amount)) from com.test.domain.Receivable as r GROUP BY r.agebucket")
    List<com.test.domain.ReceivableBeans.RecAgeBucketGroupAmountSum> recByAgeBucket();
```

Comment: You're no longer querying a Receivable, but instead are getting the results of a group aggregation.  Have your method return an entity that has a 'agebucket' and 'amount' attribute.

Comment: Thank you cafelatte. Tried that and then got the below error."No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple!" Another thing that's strange is that when I use the fully qualified name of Receivable, Intellij is telling me that the class is not an entity even though it is marked as such with @Entity

Comment: Hi Neil, any other thoughts? I've got it working with the new class with age bucket and amount attributes,  but still getting the same PersistentEntity must not be null issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@Query("select new ReceivableStats(r.agebucket, sum(r.amount)) from Receivable r group by r.agebucket")
List< ReceivableStats> recByAgeBucket();
```

or name your aliases in the query, e.g.

```
sum(r.amount) as amount
```

and have your method return an Object[].

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. If I don't include the fully qualified name, I get a "Cannot resolve symbol" underline in intellij and can't run the service. Putting the qualified name in works however, but I'm getting the same error as before unfortunately {"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}

Comment: Any thoughts on why the repository wouldn't see my entity class as an entity when mentioned in the @Query statement?

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Any chance of seeing more of the code / a small reproducible example?

Comment: I have actually gotten this to work so long as I am always returning a Receivable object. The moment I stop returning a Receivable with all of the Receivable columns, I get this same error - "persistent entity cannot be null". There's no other code really to show as SpringBoot doesn't require anything other than the repository and the query. Do you know of a way to get this to work wherin all I return is the agebucket and summed amount columns? I tried a custom class, tried Object[], and tried List<Map<String, Long>> to be returned, but nothing has worked. Is this a limitation of SpringBoot?